# How-to include two text inputs in one answer

Tags: google-forms

I have a question to Google forms.
How can I include more Text field answers in one question?

```
Example:
Q: How many children do you have in your class?
A: blue-eyed ______      brown-eyed ______
```

So I need to save two text fields (blue-eyed, brown-eyed) in one answer.

Comment: You can always 'Normalize' your question. Divide it in two different questions: How many blue-eyed children, How many brown-eyed children

Comment: Yes, you're right. But in case of 5 these question, I will have 10 in total.  So this is the case why I need this (it looks better for user to fill form with 5 questions than with 10).

Comment: I found out that I can post second question without question title and then it looks like there are two input fields. If somebody has better solution please share. thanks